# Removing quotation marks from a .txt file

Tags: python, list, file, scanning

I'm trying to scan in a set of data from a text file. It's all on one line and all contained in quotation marks

```
["0887625941",";A3:McEI_nmFa","9727427353" etc.
```

I want to store them in an array on separate rows and remove the quotation marks

```
[0887625941
 ;A3:McEI_nmFa
 9727427353
 etc.
```

I have a set of code that on paper is supposed to do exactly that but in reality seems to remove nearly all the code to the point where it's indistinguishable

```
dataList = []

result = open('data.txt')

for i in result:
    result = i.strip().split(',')

for i in result:
    result = i.replace('"', '')

for i in result:
   dataList.append(i)

for i in dataList:
   print(i)
```

---

```
Output:
"
Q
0
t
Q
y
r
h
g
e
r
^
J
m
^
9
v
M
]
n
"
]
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like valid JSON. You might want to try a JSON parser. To the problem with your code: on the second loop the iterator is exhausted and can't be used anymore.

Comment: it's not really an answer, but the quotation is done, to give characters inside a string a different meaning from outside the string.
In other words, there could be commas in the string. You have to handle that.
String.Split will not take care of this, it will also Split in the middle of a quoted string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below (assuming a.txt contains your data)

```
with open('a.txt') as f:
  data = f.read().replace('"','').replace(',','\n')
  print(data)
with open('a.txt') as f:
  # OR -  if you want to store the elements in a list, just do
  lst = f.read().replace('"','').split(',')
  print(lst)
```

output

```
[0887625941
;A3:McEI_nmFa
9727427353
['[0887625941', ';A3:McEI_nmFa', '9727427353']
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted the items in a list, not printed. Although to be fair your output does look exactly like the example.

Comment: @SimonN I agree. I have modified the answer to support both options

Comment: I guess they probably wanted to drop the square brackets too. Nothing another replace() won't fix. As one of the other commenters said this actually looks like a valid JSON array so json.loads might do the job in one line.